# linked list hash table with Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a hash table with a linked list, but it keeps giving me a Segmentation fault. I'm not sure where I did wrong. Basically,  I create a dynamic array with Node, then I use each Node as the head of the linked list. I'm struggling with this for a few days. Just couldn't figure out where it's wrong. Can anyone help, please? Here's a simple version code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


class HashTable
{
public:
    HashTable()
        : hashMap{ new Node[10] }
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            hashMap[i].next = nullptr;
        }
    }
    ~HashTable()
    {
        delete[] hashMap;
    }

    unsigned int hasher(const std::string& x)
    {
        return x[0]%10;
    }

    void add(const std::string& key)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->key = key;
        newNode->next = nullptr;

        if (hashMap[hasher(key)].next==nullptr)
        {
            hashMap[hasher(key)].next = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node* current = hashMap[hasher(key)].next;
            while (current->next != nullptr)
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
        delete newNode;
    }

    void print(std::string key)
    {
        std::cout<<hashMap[hasher(key)].next->key<<std::endl;
    }

private:

    struct Node
    {
        std::string key;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* hashMap;  
};




int main()
{
    HashTable ht;
    ht.add("Hello");
    ht.print("Hello");
}
```

Comment: `delete newNode;` in `add` is a problem. Deleting the node that was just added leaves a dangling pointer.

Comment: "Hello" and 'hello" don't hash to the same value, so even if you fix the issue with deleting the node you have to handle the fact that there's no "hello" in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I didn't delete newNode, I don't know how to deal with the memory leak issue. Also, when I delete the line of ``` delete newNode```, it still has the Segmentation fault.

Comment: `hashMap[hasher(key)].next->key` Why do you think there is a (non-null) `next`? And if there is `next`, why do you think it has the key you are looking for?

Comment: The assignment is case sensitive, "Hello" and 'hello" can be treated as different inputs. That's should be fine.

Comment: It isn't fine because `hashMap[hasher(key)].next` is a null pointer in `print`.

Comment: sorry for my typo...I should input the same key

Comment: Works fine after the edit when the node that was just added isn't deleted. https://ideone.com/u0Jdns It will leak memory, but that needs to be solved elsewhere, such as when the table is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I tried to input a key in the add function. I thought it might work. but it didn't work as I expected @ – n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing it out. I guess I can try to deallocate the memory in the destructor. 
@Retired Ninja